# Is there a simple way to add "easing" to a parallax?

Tags: jquery, drag, parallax, easing

I've created a fairly robust parallax. It uses a "timeline" concept to show items within a given frame/scene. Clicking on a trigger (date or text) will "zip" the user to that given scene. The user can also click and drag within the parallax box.

All of this works as expected.

However, it was requested that a "flick" or "easing" be added to it. That is, when the user drags and stops instead of just stopping where the user stopped dragging it needs to over-shoot gently. The harder they scroll the more over-shoot, the softer the less it over-shoots.

My idea in psudo-code fashion was this:

```
on scroll{
 startMove = getTime;
 clearTimeout(moving)
 moving =  setTimeout(){
    endTime = getTime;
    moveTime = endTime - startMove;
    speed = [decide amount to overshoot based on moveTime];
    layer1.animate({'left':layer1.position().left - (speed/layerScrollSpeed)});
 },50);
}
```

I did something like the above but it was jumpy and the layers moved around more than they needed too.

Given the sensitivity of the project I'm unable to share code and links. However, any ideas, links, suggestion, or "hey, try this" would be helpful. Thanks!